# JAVA - Problema con el condicional IF ELSE al usar el valor de un STRING

Tags: java, condiciones

El código es muy simple. Solo debo obtener el tipo de 'almacenamiento' que tiene un articulo. Este puede ser del 'depósito' o de los 'estantes/gondolas'. Al obtener ese registro, procedo a realizar un proceso diferente de cada uno.
El problema es que la condicional no me funciona, sin importar el valor que reciba.

```
String tipo = dao_articulos.obtener_tipo(art.getLocalizacion());

if (tipo == "DEPÓSITO") {

} 

if (tipo == "ESTANTE") {

}
```

He corroborado con el `System.out.print()` el valor que recibe 'tipo', y sin problemas, éste recibe los valores correctos.

Aunque el tipo sea 'DEPÓSITO' o 'ESTANTE', el código 'salta' la condicional. Sé que algo estoy haciendo mal pero no lo detecto. A veces nos complicamos tanto por cosas tan simples.

Comment: puedes colocar por favor que tipo de dato y una muestra del mismo que recibe la var `tipo`

Comment: El método `obtener_tipo` recibe un parámetro `String` y retorna un valor `String`.

Comment: y si pruebas nuevamente tu código, pero de esta manera `if(tipo == "DEPÓSITO"){
            System.out.println(1);
        }else if(tipo == "ESTANTE"){
            System.out.println(2);
        }else if(tipo == null){
            System.out.println("La var esta nula");
        }else{
            System.out.println("El valor no es conocido");
        }`

Comment: Sale la última condición `el valor no es conocido`... Por alguna razon, no se detecta el valor de `tipo`... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hola podrías utilizar la comparación de cadenas con equals de este modo

```
   String tipo = dao_articulos.obtener_tipo(art.getLocalizacion());
    if(tipo.equals("DEPÓSITO")){
     System.out.println("deposito");
    }else if(tipo.equals("ESTANTE")){
      System.out.println("estante");
    }else{
   System.out.println("no es deposito ni estantes es "+tipo);
    }
```

y para ignorar mayuscula o minusculas puedes usar equalsIgnoreCase:

```
String tipo = "DePoSITO";
if(tipo.equalsIgnoreCase("DEPOSITO")){
 System.out.println("deposito");
}
```

cabe resaltar que las tildes y/o mayusculas y minusculas son importantes.Deberia funcionarte a menos que sea otro el error.

Comment: He modificado el `return` para obtener un valor tipo `entero` y de ese modo escaparme del problema. De todos modos, al hacer lo que me pides el resultado es: `no es deposito ni estantes es DEPOSITO`. La condicional `if else` es incapaz de detectar el valor `String`, pero lo imprime sin problemas.

Comment: ya eh editado de acuerdo a tu codigo, ademas lo he probado y funciona,las tildes y/o mayusculas son importantes.

Comment: Es verdad. Funciona perfectamente sin utilizar acentos. El único detalle es que el método `equalsIgnoreCase` solo me funciona con **minúsculas**, pero no con **acentos**. Pero todo esta correcto. Gracias!